# Can't get user to sign into Google Play Games (ApiException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4:)

Tags: android

I use the following method to sign the player in:

```
private void sign_in_player_silently(){

    if(!is_signed_into_play_games()){
        GoogleSignInClient google_sign_in_client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(current_context,GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
        google_sign_in_client.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    player_account = task.getResult();
                    Games.getGamesClient(current_context,player_account).setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                }
                else{
                    Log.d("GooglePlayGames","Could not sign player in. Exception thrown:\n" + task.getException());
                }

            }
        });
    }

}
```

I've already signed my app as a release version and have the SHA1, which I put into the Linked Apps section of the Google Play Console.

I added myself as a tester, and enabled internet in AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

For some reason I still can't connect to Play Games on my account on my phone (the device I'm testing on). I get the following error:

`com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4:`

The above is printed in the Log statement.

What seems to be the problem?

EDIT: Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.1'
}
```